# Can't parse the data using JavaScriptDateTimeConverter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I try to parse simple JSON using Json.net

```
 string inputJson = @"
                {
                 ""modificationTime"" : ""\/Date(1224043200000)\/""
                 }";
```

And property is defined

```
[JsonProperty("modificationTime")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime ModificationTime { get; set; }
```

But DeserializeObject throw an exception with the following Message:
"Unexpected token or value when parsing date. Token: Date, Value: 10/15/2008 04:00:00"

Well, as far as I see it actually has parsed the date, hasn't it?
This exception is thrown from the line 68 in the JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.cs:

```
68 if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartConstructor ||  string.Compare(reader.Value.ToString(), "Date", StringComparison.Ordinal) != 0)
69            throw new Exception("Unexpected token or value when parsing date. Token: {0}, Value: {1}".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, reader.TokenType, reader.Value));
70    
71          reader.Read();
```

In this place reader.TokenType is Date and reader.Value.ToString() is 10/15/2008 04:00:00.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Json.NET deserializes dates with the format:

```
"\/Date(1224043200000)\/"
```

by default. JavaScriptDateTimeConverter is for dates with the format:

```
new Date(1234567890)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem some time ago. I found a workaround and blogged about it:

http://shico.blogspot.com/2010/07/ajaxpro-deserialize-json-datetime.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't. He wrote that if it is "/Date(1224043200000)/" than it will not work. While I use ""\/Date(1224043200000)\/"". I suppose the problem is reader.TokenType should be  JsonToken.StartConstructor. And it probably means that "\/ is parsed like this token.